# C++ std::future hangs on timeout

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking, stdasync, std-future

All

I have setup a test project for learning std::future and its use with std::async. It is a simple console app and the code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::string getLine()
{
    char rawLine[1024];
    std::cin.getline(rawLine, 1024);
    std::string line(rawLine);
    return line;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::string line("");

    while ((line != "@shutdown"))
    {
        std::future<std::string> future = std::async(getLine);

        if (future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(30)) == std::future_status::ready)
            line = future.get();
        else
        {
            future._Abandon();
            std::cout << "@:-- server shutdown\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have noticed a weird behavior with visual studion 2017. If i set the project properties->code generation->Runtime Library to /MTd or /MT this program hangs on exit and the call stack shows

```
>   futrreAsyncTest.exe!_execute_onexit_table::__l2::<lambda>() Line 206    C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),int <lambda>(void) &,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && setup, _execute_onexit_table::__l2::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 204 C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!__acrt_lock_and_call<int <lambda>(void) >(const __acrt_lock_id lock_id, _execute_onexit_table::__l2::int <lambda>(void) && action) Line 940 C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!_execute_onexit_table(_onexit_table_t * table) Line 160 C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!common_exit::__l2::<lambda>() Line 226  C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!__crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),void <lambda>(void) &,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && setup, common_exit::__l2::void <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 225    C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!__acrt_lock_and_call<void <lambda>(void) >(const __acrt_lock_id lock_id, common_exit::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && action) Line 940 C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!common_exit(const int return_code, const _crt_exit_cleanup_mode cleanup_mode, const _crt_exit_return_mode return_mode) Line 201 C++ Symbols loaded.
    futrreAsyncTest.exe!exit(int return_code) Line 293  C++ Symbols loaded.


    function    0x00d9f750 {futrreAsyncTest.exe!Concurrency::details::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for '_Task_scheduler_main_block_instance''(void)}   void(*)()
```

On the other hand if i set the project properties->code generation->Runtime Library to /MD or /MDd this program exits fine.

Any ideas why this could be happening? Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: What is `_Abandon()`?  That isn't a standard function.

Comment: Something I tried From Win 10 at c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\future

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897768/in-visual-studio-thread-local-variables-destructor-not-called-when-used-with

Comment: Yup, had to use wait_until rather than wait_for so everything gets cleaned up