# std::async from std::async in windows xp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-xp

This sample prints all 2 messages under windows7 and on ideone.com, but fails to print second message on windows xp. What im doing wrong? If it is a bug, where i should report it?

Compiled for windows xp using visual studio 2017, platform toolset v141_xp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto f1 = async(launch::async, []()->int {
        cout << "in outer async" << endl;

         auto f2 = async(launch::async, []()->int {
             cout << "in inner async" << endl;
             return 2;
         });
         f2.get();

        return 1;
    });
    f1.get();

    return 0;
}
```

UPD when using std::thread instead of std::async for inner function - it works well on both systems

```
auto f2 = thread([]()->int {
    cout << "in inner async" << endl;
    return 2;
});
f2.join();
```

UPD2

visual studio 2017 cl.exe version 19.14.26428 toolset v141_xp

commandline:

```
/permissive- /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /analyze- /Wall /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\testasync.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

UPD3 looks like launch::async is ignored when used on windows xp

```
vector<future<void>> v;
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    v.push_back(async(launch::async, []() {cout << "thread" << endl; this_thread::sleep_for(5s); }));
for( auto &f : v )
    f.get();
```

on windows7 this tooks ~6seconds to complete, on windows xp ~50 seconds

Comment: Compilers versions? Compiler commands?

Comment: So what happens? Is line `cout << "in inner async" << endl;` executed but not visible in output or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374264/4955498 but this does not explain missing text, only intermixed text. Also, the second cout happens only after the first one is completed, so intermixing does not apply in this case

Comment: under xp program just hangs, only one line "in outer async" printed

Comment: @Fl0 You should post proper problem description then. "fails to print second message" and "program just hangs" are quite different. At which line does it hang? It would be a good idea to include call stacks for running threads as well.

Comment: On windows XP does your program finishes? In Windows `std::async(...)` sits on top of thread pool. So there can be deadlocks. Inside `f1` you run new task and call `f2.get()`, which blocks until `f2` is finished. But if `auto f2 = async(...)` chose the same thread in which `f1` runs, then you have deadlock and your program should not finish. If it does, then this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows `std::async(...)` sits on top of thread pool. So there can be deadlocks. Inside `f1` you run new task and call `f2.get()`, which blocks until `f2` is finished. But if `auto f2 = async(...)` chose the same thread in which `f1` runs, then you have deadlock and your program should not finish. If it does, then this isn't the case.

**UPDATE**

Please, read about Microsoft implementation of `std::async` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/standard-library/future-functions?view=vs-2017).
It says:

> The C++ standard states that if policy is launch::async, the function creates a new thread. However the Microsoft implementation is currently non-conforming. It obtains its threads from the Windows ThreadPool, which in some cases may provide a recycled thread rather than a new one. This means that the launch::async policy is actually implemented as launch::async|launch::deferred

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898570/2795046), which reveals a particular feature of Microsoft's `std::async` implementation:

> - It limits the total number of background threads it uses, after which a call to std::async will block until a thread becomes free. On my machine, this number is 768.

So, I assume, if you have only one thread in ThreadPool, then the call to `std::async` from inside of a task will deadlock. Probably it is your case, taking into account your *UPD3*.

I really recommend to read the mentioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898570/2795046), so you could understand why Microsoft's `std::async` is different and how to use it correctly.

Comment: changing inner async to f2 = thread( lambda ); f2.join(); does the work. Is std::thread behaves differently from std::async?

Comment: When the same thread in which f1 runs is selected call to `f2.get()` will never lead to a deadlock, rather it will be executed synchronously. With your logic creating and getting values from async tasks from inside of other async tasks would lead to random deadlocks making async completely unusable...

Comment: Not sure I follow this. If both callbacks run on the same thread, how can there possibly be a deadlock between them?

Comment: Im explicitly specialize launch::async flag to start another thread immediately. It should not be a problem to start a thread from another thread...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the point is, that `f2.get()` gets blocked until `f2` is finished. But `f2` will never finish because the thread is blocked.

Comment: @nicolai That's a really silly implementation if so. If `f2` is destined for the same thread, `f2.get()` should simply invoke the callback without blocking at all. That's how it works when async decides not to use a worker thread. Why would it block waiting for something it wants to do on its own thread? Silly!

Comment: @VTT > With your logic creating and getting values from async tasks from inside of other async tasks would lead to random deadlocks making async completely unusable...

Yes, standard tasking system can't be used safely. There is talk from Sean Parent, see http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2017-01-18-concurrency/2017-01-18-concurrency.pdf.

Comment: @nicolai And which part of the linked document covers this case? `async` with `launch::async` is required to behave as if a new thread has been spawned, and the thread executing `f1` becomes ready to execute `f2` when `f2.get()` is called. This should work regardless of whether implementation uses thread pools, spawns new threads or runs everything in main thread.