# C++ Which thread pool is cppreference.com talking about?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I was reading the description of std::async at cppreference.com.
The first description says :

> The template function async runs the function f asynchronously
>   (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a **thread
>   pool**) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the
>   result of that function call.

. [cppreference link]: [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

What is the thread pool **cppreference.com**  is talking about ?

I read the standard draft N4713 (C++ 17) and there is no mention of a possible thread pool usage.
I also know that there is no thread pool in the standard C++ as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cppreference and the C++ standard are in fact at odds about this.  cppreference says this (emphasis and strikethrough mine):

> The template function `async` runs the function `f` asynchronously (<strike>potentially</strike> optionally in a separate thread **which may be part of a thread pool**).

Whereas the [C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.async#3.1) says this:

> If `launch::async` is set in `policy`, [`std::async`] calls [the function f] **as if in a new thread of execution** ...

And these are clearly two different things.

Only Windows' implementation of `std::async` uses a thread pool AFAIK, while gcc and clang start a new thread for every invocation of `std::async` (when `launch::async` is set in `policy`), and thus follow the standard.

More analysis here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898570/5743288

Comment: Thanks for  the precision that a  thread pool is only used on the windows' implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Purely hypothetical. cppreference is trying to tell you that standard allows execution of the task in the thread pool (as opposed to launching a new thread to execute it). And although standard may not explicitly allow it, there is nothing which would prohibit it either.

I am not aware of any implementation which would use a thread pool for `std::async`.

Comment: So If get it, it is message addressed to the compiler implementer ? Because now I'm currious on how I could tell std::async to use a dedicated thread pool

Comment: Could be. I am not really sure what's the significance of this note.

Comment: The significance of this note is that if your function `f` calls `std::this_thread::get_id()`, it may get the same `id` back for different executions.

Comment: @RaymondChen that could be the case even if it is executed on the new thread for every launch.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm ok with the part where cppreference says that f could potentially be run on a separate thread,which we as user can control by setting the launch policy to std::launch::async or std::launch::deffered. But for the actual thread which run f to be part of a thread pool it means that somehow std::async can be instructed to use a thread pool. Sow how do we get that ?

Comment: @cyrildz may be I am not clear enough. You can't direct `std::async` to use thread pool or not use the thread pool. It is decided by implementation (and the decision right now is **not** using the pool)

Comment: @SergeyA No worry , I'm fine with your answer. It makes sense to me. I was just not convinced by the comment from RaymondChen

Comment: I've written a program that initially used thread creation/join for accumulating results from a lot of FFT processing. I initially saw only a 2x speedup on my 6 core machine. But after changing the code to use async, I saw about a 5x increase in the multi-threaded part of the code. I chalk this up to async using a thread pool so the overhead of thread creation/destruction is avoided. Windows 10 x64 with VS2017.

Comment: @SergeyA it also means that your `thread_local` variables may be shared between multiple invocations of `f`.

Comment: _And although standard may not explicitly allow it, there is nothing which would prohibit it either._ Yes there is, please see my answer.