# Is std::packaged_task<T> (Function Template) an std::async (FT) with an invoked function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, difference, packaged-task

Trying to work with `packaged_task<T>`

`std::async` creates a thread executed asynchronously and process data which we can access into, using the class template `std::future<T>` and the `get()` method.

What should i know about how `packaged_task<T>` works, in difference with `std::async` ?

And was the thread related to `packaged_task<T>`, created when we invoked the `task(x)` function ?

Taking the code example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{

    int x(0),xr(0);

    std::future<int> fdata = std::async(std::launch::async,[&](int data) mutable throw() ->
                                        int
                                        {data++;
                                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(2));
                                        return data;}
                                        ,x);

    std::packaged_task<int(int)> task([&](int data) mutable throw() ->
                                        int
                                        {data++;
                                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(2));
                                        return data;}
                                        );
    std::future<int> xrp = task.get_future();

    task(x);

    xr=fdata.get();

    std::cout<<xr<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<xrp.get()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::async(ploicy, callable, args...)
```

launches a new thread (if the resources are available) if the policy is `std::async::launch`.

If the policy is not determined, it may launch or not.

If the policy is `std::async::deferred`, won't launch.

while `std::packaged_task` wraps your callable so that it can be invoked asynchronously using a new thread like

```
auto t1 = std::thread(std::move(taskObj), args...);
....
t1.join();
```

But If you used it as you do in your example, it wouldn't launch a new thread. It doesn't launch a new thread by itself but it can be used to do that.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `std::async` on Windows is a bit weird, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897768/in-visual-studio-thread-local-variables-destructor-not-called-when-used-with/50898570#50898570